# Rename tag modular-form to modular-forms

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tagging

I hope everyone agrees that the plural is a better tag.

Comment: I've gone ahead and retagged; probably a mod can remove the other one.

Comment: I think that moderators have the ability to merge tags, so that bumping to the front page is unnecessary.

Comment: Well, there were only five questions using that tag; so not much of a problem IMHO. On the other hand, if it were as big a tag as `number-theory` ...

Answer (score 1):

This looks complete to me: [modular-forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-forms) is the only one I see.